# Scaphism 2.0: Execution by Compost

Tags: biology, medicine

As a swamp used for scaphism is about to become a national park, a local government of my psychotic dictatorship is looking for an alternative way to carry out such executions.

A local farmer has proposed that the condemned are either tightly tied or given a paralytic agent and then put into a pile of compost up to the head.

**What would be the effects of such treatment, provided that the condemned is fed every day and a medical professional is always present to administer adrenaline and light painkillers to prolong the suffering?** How long would it take the condemned to die, and how would that novelty, eco-friendly method of execution feel? Is it better if the criminal is put into the compost vertically, or horizontally (e.g. the body laying on the ground and covered in compost)? What can be done to postpone death and intensify the suffering further?

Comment: I'm pretty sure execution or torture isn't something we should assist in, even for worldbuilding.

Comment: There ARE tags for this.

Comment: Grim factoid: the traditional penalty for Russian women who killed their husbands was to bury them upright up to their necks and leave them to die; sometimes relatives did feed them. It's pretty famous, and you will find descriptions in travel books and historical novels.

Comment: Having tags does not mean everything is allowed. For questions like "would someone need a psychiatrist or psychologist after waterboarding?", or "How could you prevent a deadly shock from the electric chair" could call for these tags, while not asking how to horrifically torture and kill someone. But I'm fairly new here. I might be wrong in my statement.

Comment: @Trioxidane - Those things are on topic here. Worldbuilding isn't just flowers and bunnies. Or even bunny eating flowers. See [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7186/answer-contains-description-of-real-life-animal-torture-and-my-edit-request-was/7188#7188); and also [this question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/should-questions-requesting-help-creating-a-terrorist-attack-be-answered/4167#4167).

Comment: @Trioxidane though we are aware that torture isn't exactly seen as a good moral choice, it's completely on topic so long as it follows the guidelines. I myself tried answering a post about how to ensure someone is kept alive during and after completely flaying them (spoilers: its not possible).

Comment: @Trioxidane Put another way, Worldbuilding is about creating settings for works of fiction.  That includes the horror genre; so, sometimes questions come up about how to set up scenarios that make horror stories... well horrible.  Even outside of the horror genre, acts of true evil must often be told as the backdrop against which a hero's, virtues are measured.

Comment: Don't worry I get it. Still, I wonder why it needs to be as painful as possible. Your imagination can already serve enough painful methods for execution. Making it worse or the worst isn't really adding anything to it. And you can look at medieval torture and modern torture enough. Families can be punished in North Korea and being put on a spike can last for days in some cases. Do we need a forum to add more, or can you just search for some and add your spin? Why is buried alive in compost with some additions of drugs and feed to live longer not enough?

Comment: @Trioxidane That is a plot question... which ironically is not on topic.  But, if Medwedian is writing a story where the main character is subjected to this form of execution, just saying "he was buried in compost" may not be enough. There could be an entire chapter devoted to the person's experience as you see interactions between him and his captors and/or friends visiting him.  If you need the hero to escape, but only after several days of torture, you would need to know if this method has already killed him or if he could walk away just needing a bath.

Comment: If it's the last chapter in a book, and this is how your hero dies, then ending abruptly on "he was buried in compost... and umm died" would be crazy anti-climatic; so, knowing all the stages that he would go through may be important.  I think if Medwedian was actually the kind of person to kill someone this way, he would not be asking WB.SE he'd be tying someone down and seeing for himself.

Comment: You're missing the point. What is the use of the most painful compost torture execution, if a painful compost torture execution will already do the trick? He's not asking in what stages someone will die and how if he can't find this information himself. He asks only the worst, for which I can see no benefit to his story compared to a painful one.

Answer (score 6):

**The farmer is a kindly soul**

I am serious here.  The compost will have to get dug up and either inadvertently or deliberately turned in order to bury the victim in it.  Why is this significant?  Because freshly turned compost gets *hot*, 60 degrees C or more.  Even if the sadists plug in an IV drip to prevent dehydration, with the entire body buried the only significant heat loss will be through the head.  Result:  once the heat ramps up to over 40-50 degrees the victim will suffer from extreme heat stroke and be dead in a few hours.  Still a stupidly cruel method of execution, but shorter duration than is being aimed for - daily feeding will not be a factor in the victim's rate of death.

The farmer would know about the temperature compost gets to and the effects of heat exhaustion / heat stroke, but obviously feels no reason to educate the ignorant city-bred torturers.  The attending medical professional may be able to work it out from a knowledge of basic biology, but given that they are ready to provide mild painkillers(!) it's fairly clear that they're not on board with the long-duration torture and death program either, especially as they need to hang around next to a compost heap until the victim dies.  I like the idea that the medical professional and farmer cooked up this idea together to minimise the cruelty around them - the medic helps the victim on their way in the first few hours, then keeps sending back daily fake status reports of the victim's ongoing suffering while helping out as a vet on the farm.

Answer (score 1):

### The Farmer as an Evil Bastard

While the kind farmer knows that compost gets up to 60°C quickly killing the victim, it is only a matter of time before a farmer realizes that compost stays cooler the closer to the surface you get; so, instead of burying the victim vertically for a quick death, the evil farmer would propose that you bury the victim horizontally so that he can maintain a temperature on the victim just shy of causing a heat stroke.

The victim's skin would slowly burn and blister over a longer period of time (from the caustic nature of compost as much as anything).  As blisters start to rupture, pathogens and decomposers would start to invade the victim's body.  At this point fever would start to set in, so the evil farmer would want to strip away some of the compost allowing the victim to stay cool enough to stay alive.  Ecoil poisoning will also cause the victim to begin vomiting and experiencing diarrhea, which he will be trapped in as well. Being unable to fight off the constant invasion of bacteria to the bloodstream hemolytic uremic syndrome will set in causing complete kidney failure.  Toxins will then continue to build up in the blood stream until reaching fatal levels.

Death from total kidney failure without dialysis in a normal scenario would take at least a week to kill; though, it may be accelerated in this case (further research is <strike>needed</strike> not advised).

The smart victim will try to inhale their own vomit at the first signs of ecoil poisoning for a quick end; so, burying them upside down or sideways should help keep them from taking the "easy way out".

If you are talking about a medically advanced civilization. The person could probably be administered enough antibiotics and an dialysis to extend punishment, in this case I suspect the victim might survive until such point that the beatles and other decomposers in the soil cause enough hemorrhaging that he bleeds out.

Your final option if you really want it to last is to not leave him in the compost at all.  Instead, you could torture a person indefinitely by burying them until the point they start getting sick, then pull them out.  Wait until their infections pass, then put them back in again since most people will naturally recover from ecoil poisoning on their own as long as you don't keep them buried in the stuff.

You may also start to see a culture emerge here of bribing your executioner.  Throughout history, people would often pay their own executioner to make sure the axe is freshly sharpen, to poison them before crucifixion, or other such things to ensure a more merciful death.  In this case, the farmers may take bribes to make sure the pitchfork "accidentally" impales them while sifting the compost or to introduce poisons to the compost that might lead to a faster death.